# I would like to extract indexes for each element in a list

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

list2 = ["A", "A", "C", "B", "E", "A", "C", "B", "E", "D"]
```

I want to create a list of lists of indexes for each elements as:

```
[[0,1,5], [3, 7], [2, 6], [9], [4,8]]
```

I have tried this:

```
for i in list1:
    list3 = [j for j,x in enumerate(list2) if x == i]
    print(list3)
```

But I got these separate outcomes:

```
[0, 1, 5]
[3, 7]
[2, 6]
[9]
[4, 8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest is create one more list and append to that list

```
In [28]: list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    ...: list2 = ["A", "A", "C", "B", "E", "A", "C", "B", "E", "D"]

In [29]: data = []

In [30]: for i in list1:
    ...:      list3 = [j for j,x in enumerate(list2) if x == i]
    ...:      data.append(list3)
    ...:

In [31]: data
Out[31]: [[0, 1, 5], [3, 7], [2, 6], [9], [4, 8]]
```

OR

```
In [32]: data = []

In [33]: for i in list1:
    ...:      data.append([j for j,x in enumerate(list2) if x == i])

In [35]: data
Out[35]: [[0, 1, 5], [3, 7], [2, 6], [9], [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as a list comprehension.

```
>>> list3 = [[j for j,x in enumerate(list2) if x == i] for i in list1]
>>> list3
[[0, 1, 5], [3, 7], [2, 6], [9], [4, 8]]
```

However, you can improve the time complexity by iterating only once over `list2` and not once for each element of `list1`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for idx, el in enumerate(list2):
...     d[el].append(idx)
... 
>>> res = [d[el] for el in list1]
>>> res
[[0, 1, 5], [3, 7], [2, 6], [9], [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside another list comprehension :

```
list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
list2 = ["A", "A", "C", "B", "E", "A", "C", "B", "E", "D"]
list3 =[[j for j,x in enumerate(list2) if x == i] for i in list1]
print(list3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a simple list comprehension.. something as in

```
[[j for j,x in enumerate(list2) if x == i] for i in list1]
```

Comment: My bad.. I had hit the post button and realized that another answer had already been posted. I'll take care in the future.